# Upgrading MonoRail - $HtmlHelper.InputFile & $HtmlHelper.DateTime missing?

Tags: castle-monorail

I upgraded MonoRail to the latest version and now $HtmlHelper.InputFile and $HtmlHelper.DateTime don't get parsed. Were these removed and are there equivalents for these now?

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$HtmlHelper.InputFile is now $FormHelper.FileField.

It appears that $HtmlHelper.DateTime is gone, even though I see documentation for it and haven't seen anything online indicating that it has been removed. I ended up replacing it with a textbox and using a jQuery date picker.